# Считывание слитного текста и разделение его на переменные C++

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, int

Вводится строка: **22:13:44**

**Вводится слитно**, с ":", именно так "**22:13:44**"
Нужно обработать эту строчку и взять эти числа, то есть создать 3 переменные a, b, c
И записать значения обязательно в ***целочисленные*** переменные.
То есть в **итоге должно быть** int a=22,b=13,c=44;

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код который разделит этот ввод на такие переменные

Я пытался сделать подобное, но запутался в типах переменных и в их обработке

Comment: *"Я пытался сделать подобное, но запутался"* Вот и покажите ваш код.

Comment: @Владислав для вас никто код писать полностью не будет. Здесь вам могут помочь, указать на ошибку, а не написать весь код за вас. Какой бы код не был бы плохой, от него люди могут оттолкнуться и помочь в решении вашей проблемы.

Comment: `int a, b, c;
 char delim;
 cin >> a >> delim >> b >> delim >> c;`

Comment: "записать значения обязательно в целочисленные переменные"
"должно быть int"
"Я пытался сделать подобное, но запутался в типах переменных и в их обработке"

Answer (score 1):

Программа, для которой безразлична, что вы введете. Она всеравно будет читать только первые три числа:

```
int  numbers[3], i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    char smb = std::cin.peek();
    if(smb >= '0' && smb <= '9')
        std::cin >> numbers[i++];
    else
        std::cin.ignore();
}
int a{numbers[0]}, b{numbers[1]}, c{numbers[2]};
std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c;
```

Это всего лишь один из многих вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с самого простого кода. Если позиции символов всегда одинаковые, то можно написать прям так

```
string s = "22:13:44";
int a = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + s[1] - '0';
```

ну или секунды

int c = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + s[7] - '0';

Грубо, но полностью рабочее.

Можно пойти дальше, и сделать где то так

```
int a = stoi(s.substr(0,2));
int b = stoi(s.substr(3,2));
```

(но если что, это с++11 и старше. Но если Ваш компилятор это не поддерживает, то у меня для Вас плохие новости).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a;
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> b;
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> c;
        cout << a << endl << b << endl << c;
        return 0;
}
```

Простой варинат. На выходе получаете три числа. Между последними может стоять абсолютно любой символ. Тов. AR Hovsepyan выше предложил более универсальное решение, т.к. между числами может находиться любое кол-во знаков.